# Skip a sql statement from replication (Mysql) ? [ Disables or enables binary logging for the current session ]

Tags: mysqli

I want to do some inserts on a table (master mysql DB) but I dont want to replicate without effecting the replication process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SET sql_log_bin = {0|1} Disables or enables binary logging for the current session (sql_log_bin is a session variable) if the client has the SUPER privilege. The statement fails with an error if the client does not have that privilege